# Swift namespace conflict perfect storm

Tags: swift

I'm 90+% certain that this is a loophole in the language design that makes this type now completely inaccessible.

My own project has a class `Analytics`.  The 3rd party cocoapod that I'm using also has a MODULE named `Analytics`.  INSIDE this module, somebody decided to use NS_SWIFT_NAME to "rename" the internal ObjC `SEGAnalytics` class to.. you guessed it.. `Analytics`.  So we have my own `Analytics` class, a module named `Analytics` and an exported class of that module named `Analytics`, but only indirectly.

The problem:

If I need to (and I do) access Analytics.SEGAnalytics from one of my files, the ONLY time swift will even consider that Analytics is referring to a module, is through the import statement, `import class Analytics.SEGAnalytics`.  HOWEVER, once I try to *use* the type like so `SEGAnalytics.shared.identify()`, the compiler complains that "SEGAnalytics" has been renamed to Analytics".  If I try to comply, `Analytics` ends up resolving to my own class type.  If I try to disambiguate through `Analytics.SEGAnalytics.identify()` or `Analytics.Analytics.identify()`, the very first `Analytics` type is not interpreted as a module, but my own class type and fails.

The only solution that I can think of is to rename my *own* heavily Analytics class which is not acceptable.  Cue the "if this was C++, this problem would have been solved in less than 5 min" speech..  :|

Comment: It would be fun if you could write a minimal bug reproducible project. So we can check on that.

Answer (score 1):

Okay.  Workaround in place, possibly only one.  I used ObjC to re-expose the class static methods via a disambinguated wrapper class and then exposed that back to my main app via standard bridging header.

Comment: Facing the same issue. Can you explain how you went about doing this?